# How do I find the index of submitted input while using .map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, ejs

I am using the Array.prototype.map() method, to display an array into a table. This table also contains an input field and submit button for every instance of the Array.prototype.map() output. How could I track what position in the array was submitted, or is it not possible?

```
<tbody>
         <% qryData.map(function(item,i){%>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <%=item.SystemID%>
            </td>
             <td>
                <%=item.SystemName%>
             </td>
              <td>
               <input  type="text" name="txtLabID"  size="12" maxlength="20"> 
              </td>
               <td align="center">
                 <button type="submit" name="AddUpdate" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="itemIndex" value="<%=i%>"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <% })%>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your map function looks like, but you can track the index of arrays when manipulating them with the `.map` method.

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
numbers.map(function(number, index) {
   console.log('number: '  + number + ' index:' + index);
});
//OUTPUT
// number: 1 index:0
// number: 5 index:1
// number: 10 index:2
// number: 15 index:3
```

Comment: My goal is to pass the index of the submitted input to the back end for further manipulation. For instance if I enter data into the first item of the map item instance and enter submit I want to pass the index of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the `data-index` attribute to each submit button and catch submit event to extract this `data-index` and add to data you are sending to backend?

if you have

```
<td align="center">
  <button type="submit" name="AddUpdate" data-index=<%= i %> class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
</td>
```

then you can do

```
$('table button').on('click', function() {
  let index = this.data('index')

  // send your request here
});
```

OR

If you use forms in your table then wrap your input field, hidden field and submit button into separate form and it will submit your index along input field value.